# How to replace the client authentication using azure Ad credentials using MSI in .Net core Startup configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, clientcredential

How to replace the client authentication using azure Ad credentials using MSI in .Net core Startup configuration?

I am using Azure Ad credentials in appsettings.config and authenticating the client in startup configuration but as per the S360 compliance it should be replaced with MSI.

Could anybody suggest how to implement MSI in .Net Core.

I am using key vault certificates thumbprints.

Comment: What is the version of your App?

Comment: Thanks Harshitha for pitching into this. I am using .Net Core3.1

Comment: Did u get a chance to look at this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp)

Comment: Thanks!  I have gone through this doc but no where it is mentioned like how to generate a token to authenticate the service in startup.cs.  I want to implement MSI in startup.cs to generate a token. currently using "azureAd" credentials from appsetting.json

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet